# Need to high light letters on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h6tsdq0w/2/) is the fiddle where i have search and working good but i want to change the existing code for getting letters background highlighted not total word. only letters background highlight........

Make changes in this code........

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  value = $(this);
  if (value.val() == "") {
    $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr td"), function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    })
    return;
  }
  $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr td"), function() {
    if (!($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(value).val().toLowerCase()) == -1)) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What did you try so far, cause this just looks like you took a piece of code, and hope to get a working piece of code without actually doing anything

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if(!($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searched_term) == -1)){
    $(this).html(original_text.replace(searched_term, "<mark style='background: yellow'>"+searched_term+"</mark>"));
}   
else{
    $(this).text($(this).text());   
}
```

Basically the idea is to replace the searched term with an html element so that we can highlight it easily with css.

**demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/h6tsdq0w/6/**

Comment: Thank you...... but the check boxes are missing if we type something in the search box....... can u please fix it

Comment: @KoteswaraRao fixed it https://jsfiddle.net/h6tsdq0w/6/

Comment: @KoteswaraRao updated the fiddle to the latest version. 6th version is the correct one

Comment: Thank you very much @aelor.......

Comment: It will destroy events and triggers regeneration of the DOM!

Comment: @dude there are no events attached to the tds in particular. Don't know which events you are concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

into this:

```
$(this).css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6tsdq0w/3/)

You should replace all your

```
$(this).css('background-color','rgba(0,0,0,0)');
```

with

```
$(this).css('color', 'white');
```

and

```
$(this).css('background-color','red');
```

with

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: letters should not change color...... background color of letter should change......